# How would I properly include nasm functions in cpp project?

Tags: c++, cmake, x86, nasm, ld

I am trying to include a function I have coded in nasm into a project that is in c++.

When I try to include the function in the cpp file using the extern keyword and compile the project, linker (ld) fails with "undefined reference to `rnd_by_seed(unsigned long long)".

Almost as if there was missing some reference in cmakelists file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(App)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
#enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(NASM_COMPILER nasm)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT elf64)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS>
-f ${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT}  -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE>")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Tools/rnd_byseed.asm)
add_executable(App ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

here's the nasm function I am trying to execute:

```
global rnd_by_seed

;------------------------------------------
; return random number by seed value
; @param rdi seed value (unsigned 64bit integer)
; @return rax random number (64bit unsigned)
rnd_by_seed:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov    eax, dword [rsp+8] 
    mov    ebx, 16807 
    mul    ebx
    mov    esi, edx 
    mov    edi, eax 
    mov    eax, dword [rsp+4] 
    mul    ebx 
    add    eax, esi 
    adc    edx, 0 

   
    shl    eax, 1
    rcl    edx, 1
    shr    eax, 1
    
    add    edx, edi 
    adc    eax, 0 
    xchg eax, edx
    
    test edx, 80000000h
    jz Store
    and    edx, 7fffffffh 
    add    eax, 1 
    adc    edx, 0

    Store:

   mov    dword [rsp+4], edx
   mov    dword [rsp+8], eax

   mov    rax, qword [rsp+8] 
   add rsp, 16
leave
ret
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" unsigned long long rnd_by_seed(unsigned long long seed);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    // call rnd_rnd_by_seed function
    auto val = rnd_by_seed(12);
    printf("val = %llu", val);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to look at different methods for including nasm files into cmakelists file, got worse results. This is the only cmakelists file that does not fail when reloading the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just need to uncomment the `enable_language(ASM_NASM)` line.

```
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT elf64)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS -f ${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT} -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE>")
```

Or enable ASM_NASM at project level.

```
project(App C CXX ASM_NASM)
```

---

However, your assembly looks wrong - assuming x64 SysV ABI, I see at least the following issues:

- the first 64-bit argument is passed in via RDI, not stack
- the value of register RBX must be preserved
- writing to `[rsp+4]`, `[rsp+8]` will damade the stack
- `add rsp, 16` is bogus

Comment: Well the add rsp is to deallocate local variables?

I know the correct way of creating local variables is to sub from the rsp and reference each var with a base pointer. For example: mov [rbp - 4], eax

using such convention would give me seg fault in many instances.

Comment: RSP is just a register like any other. `mov [...], eax` does not change its value, `push`, `pop`, `call`, `ret`, `enter`, `leave`, `add rsp,`, `sub rsp,` and alike change it. Your RSP never moved down 16 bytes, but you're trying to move it up 16 bytes. In the end it will be wrong and the program will segfault.

Comment: Oh, for unknown reason I did delete sub rsp, 16 line at the start (I was removing commented out parts of the code).

So the thing is that after subbing the rsp by 16 and then trying to "mov [rbp - 8], rax" to store a local 64bit variable would result in gibberish. when trying to access data, or into seg fault, do you know of any proper resource that covers local variable conventions, all knowledge I could find is what I have described in all my posts.